# Best practice for using the SAS EuroBonus program as a family

Tags: loyalty-programs, star-alliance, sas

We are a family of four, two adults and two children. What are the current best practices when flying using the SAS EuroBonus program? I already have an EuroBouns account but the rest of the family does not. We are not intending to spend any points on this coming flight, only to earn points/miles.
Are there any differences when not flying SAS but instead on a partnered Star Alliance airline?

Comment: My main interest is to not lose out too much actually. We will probably not be flying enough to reach the higher status classes. I suppose I might be trying to ask if every family member should have their own EuroBonus account. I myself have a fair amount of points saved up but the rest of the family doesn't (not having any accounts yet). We are still a bit new to this whole loyalty program thing.

Comment: SAS had a family pooling program, but they're changing it somehow and will [announce the new rules in the fall](http://www.flysas.com/en/us/eurobonus/about-eurobonus/family-pooling/). It's worth seeing what happens then. In the meantime, you might as well make accounts for family members and let them earn points. You're paying for the ticket either way, and the ticket comes with points whether you receive them into an account or not. Worst case is they wind up being useless to you.

Comment: You might consider also obtaining the EuroBonus Mastercard or American Express http://www.flysas.com/en/us/eurobonus/partner-index-earn/, earning points for usage. It doesn't appear as extensive as my Delta American Express (a point for every dollar charged), but it can be useful when you fly less frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS launched Point Sharing in late 2018. From the website:

> When you start or join Point Sharing, all your existing EuroBonus points are transferred to the Point Sharing account. During the time you are part of the group all the EuroBonus points that you earn are transferred to the Point sharing account.

https://www.sas.se/en/eurobonus/point-sharing/#/point-sharing (Swedish)
https://www.sas.fi/en/eurobonus/point-sharing/#/point-sharing (English)

Answer (score 2):

It seems the current best method for a family is to each get their own EuroBonus account and earn points there. For family members that are eligible and will spend the requisite amounts connecting a MasterCard or American Express card linked to the account should be considered (http://www.flysas.com/en/us/eurobonus/partner-index-earn/). For those that can wait with their bookings it might be better to wait for the announcement of SAS new family pooling program, said to be coming "fall of 2016" (http://www.flysas.com/en/us/eurobonus/about-eurobonus/family-pooling/).
Thanks to @Dorothy, @pnuts and @Zach Lipton for helpful links and comments.